# Python Script - Improve Speed

Tags: python, performance

I have a working Python script that checks the 6,300 or so sites we have to ensure they are up by sending an HTTP request to each and measuring the response. Currently the script takes about 40 min to run completely, I was interested in possibly some other ways to speed up the script, two thoughts were either threading or multiple running instances.

This is the order of execution now:

1. MySQL query to get all of the active domains to scan (6,300 give or take)
2. Iterate through each domain and using urllib send an HTTP request to each
3. If the site doesn't return '200' then log the results
4. repeat until complete

This seems like it could possibly be sped up significantly with threading but I am not quite sure how that process flow would look since I am not familiar with threading.

If someone could offer a sample high-level process flow and any other pointers for working with threading or offer any other insights on how to improve the script in general it would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using a purpose-built monitoring system?

Comment: We have and we use a purpose built tool to monitor 10 or so of our sites to enure the server is up, but the tool doesn't handle 6,300+ domains to watch. Plus the server uptime is only a small component of this, we have more build and deployment errors that would typically not be able to be captured using those tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flow would look something like this:

1. Create a domain Queue
2. Create a result Queue
3. MySQL query to get all of the active domains to scan
4. Put the domains in the domain Queue
5. Spawn a pool of worker threads
6. Run the threads
7. Each worker will get a domain from the domain Queue, send a request and put the result in the result Queue
8. Wait for the threads to finish
9. Get everything from the result Queue and log it

You'll probably want to tune the number of threads, thus the pool, and not just 6300 threads for every domain.

Comment: `Spawn a pool of worker threads` could also read `Spawn a pool of worker processes`. See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at scrapy framework. It's made for web scraping. It's asynchronus build on twisted and pretty fast.

In your case you can just get list of domains to scrape, and only see if it will return 200 without actually scraping anything. It should be much faster.

Here's the link:
http://scrapy.org/

Answer (score 1):

Threading is **definitely** what you need. It will remove the serialized nature of your algorithm, and since it is mostly IO bounded, you will gain a lot by sending HTTP requests in parallel.

Your flow would become:

1. MySQL query to get all of the active domains to scan (6,300 give or take)
2. Iterate through each domain and create a thread that will use `urllib` to send an HTTP request to each
3. Log the results in threads

You can make this algorithm better by creating a `n` worker threads with queues, and add domains to queues instead of creating one thread per each domain. I just wanted to make things a little bit easier for you since you're not familiar with threads.

Comment: Pablo thanks for the response. With the threading do you typically limit in any way the number of threads you allow to run concurrently?

Comment: Yes. You probably have an OS LIMIT for threads you are allowed to create. You can overcome that by creating a bound number of **worker threads** to do the requests for you. That will require to have a QUEUE of tasks.

Answer (score -1):

I guees you should go for threading, taking under investigation the optimal number of processes to start in order to avoid killing your client. Python manual offers good examples by the way take a look here [Download multiple pages concurrently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491993/download-multiple-pages-concurrently/1493005#1493005)

and to [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html), [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#module-threading), [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing)